# How to append to a path with additional objects in Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have data structures as such:

```
karmadots/events = 

{
  "event1": {
    "categories" : ["fun"],
    "name": "Some Title"
  }
}
```

I want to be able to append to categories and make it so it has ["fun", "outside"]. How can I achieve this? When I update child values on the event path, the entire categories path gets reset.

EDIT:

```
    @IBAction func acceptUser(sender: AnyObject) {

    //  eventRef = karmadots/events (above)
    var myRef = eventRef.childByAppendingPath("event1")
    var eventDataOne = [
        "categories":["fun"]
    ]
    myRef.updateChildValues(eventDataOne)

    // categories = ["fun"]

    var eventDataTwo = [
        //I want to be able to append to categories instead of overwriting
        "categories":["outside"]
    ]
    myRef.updateChildValues(eventDataTwo)

    // categories = ["outside"] BUT I want it to be ["fun", "outside"]
}
```

I want to be able append to categories on my second call.

Comment: It sounds like you already tried something. If so, please *edit* your question to include the code that you tried.

Comment: First off, arrays are problematic in real-time distributed data [[1](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase)], [[2](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)]. Second, this example doesn't explain the origin of standbyRef, nor does your sample data include any structure with an inviteeUserID. It's going to be hard to provide any advice when the question is fragmented and the examples misleading. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Kato Sorry, updated the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update is not a deeply recursive merge. Check out this blurb from the API docs for update:

> This will overwrite only children enumerated in the "value" parameter
>   and will leave others untouched. Note that the update function is
>   equivalent to calling set() on the named children; it does not
>   recursively update children if they are objects. Passing null as a
>   value for a child is equivalent to calling remove() on that child.

Thus, to "update" your categories, you would need to run update directly on those, rather than the parent:

```
var myRef = eventRef.childByAppendingPath("event1/categories");
myRef.updateChildValues({"one": 1});
myRef.updateChildValues({"two": 2});
```

As previously mentioned, you aren't going to be able to accomplish this sort of activity using array indices. How do we know which item we are actually "updating"? If another user adds or removes an item from the array, all the fluid, sequential keys have changed and my update is now erratic and unpredictable (see the links from my comments above).

Instead, what you probably want to do here is utilize `childByAutoId`. This is covered in the guide for saving data. There is an [entire section dedicated to saving lists](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html#section-lists) covering all the pitfalls you've encountered here and the correct solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using firebase function `$set`, which replaces everything at that node with the new data. Try using `$push` instead, that will append the new data to the existing data.